# ORA-06550: line 1, column 15: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to &#39;CMPPROJECTPROCSELECT

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have been working with asp.net webservices.The webservice includes retriving values from oracle database using stored procedure. I am new to webservices, I know its been a small mistake. The error which I have been getting is

> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to
>   'CMPPROJECTPROCSELECT

procedure code for oracle SQL DEVELOPER

```
create or replace PROCEDURE CMPPROJECTPROCSELECT( 
p_projectname IN VARCHAR2,
p_description OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
SELECT DESCRIPTION INTO p_description FROM CMPPROJECT WHERE PROJECTNAME=p_projectname;
COMMIT;
END;
```

WEBSERVICE CODE(.asmx)

```
[WebMethod]
    public string SendData(string name)
    {
        string descrip="";
        cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        con.Open();
        cmd = new OracleCommand("CMPPROJECTPROCSELECT", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p_projectname", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = name;
        cmd.Parameters["p_description"].Value = descrip;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        return descrip;

    }
```

What i have need to change...is it the way of getting parameters or in procedure itself.

Comment: `PROJECTNAME=p_projectname` shouldn't be `PROJECTNAME=:p_projectname` to specify it as a parameter in sp definition?

Comment: GETTING ERROR IN db as Error(6,74): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'P_PROJECTNAME'

Comment: @SonerGönül its in SP already, why would you still use bind variable?

Comment: @AbrahamLincoln Your SP is already correct as far as i know. Maybe you are getting the error when you are calling the procedure. You should have 2 paremeters inside the parenthesis. one for the input and one for the output as you have declared in your SP